# Most intuitive keyboard shortcut for search & replace dialog

Tags: search, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Extending the [question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41224/what-keyboard-shortcut-should-be-implemented-for-a-search-replace-dialog) what would be the most intuitive solution for the Search & Replace and maybe Find dialog?

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>H</kbd> -- Gnome, Windows
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> -- KDE
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> -- Mac OS

Which others are common and where?

From a [comparison on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing) it kinda evolved out of the keyboard layout (F-G-H): Ctrl F for Find, Ctrl G for Next, and Ctrl H for Replace (?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what operating system you're used to. But beeing a Windows guy, I still think Mac uses the right shortcut. `CTRL + F` for find (where you also can replace), is the most intuitive shortcut IMHO.